# Android and Ruby on Rails - Object Mapping

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails

I have a Ruby on Rails web application, and I'm currently working on an Android application. I would like for the android application to make calls to the Rails application and make local objects from the results.

For iOS, there is a framework called RestKit that does a great job mapping Objective-C objects to remote Ruby on Rails objects. What are the alternatives for Android?

Are there any great examples or blogs out there that sync up Android and Ruby on Rails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring for android http://www.springsource.org/spring-android has feature RestClient http://static.springsource.org/spring-android/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/rest-template.html

Third party object mappers need to be set there, I recommend google-gson.